# Touch gestures doesn't work in Scrollview (Xcode, Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, scrollview

I try to use Buttons inside a scrollview.
But they are not "touchable".

My apps without scrollview are working.

I checked if user input is enabled but it is.

Hope somebody can give me an advice.

Regards

[image]

Comment: Did you write any code for that?

Comment: can u share your project ?

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: Yes but not much, I just did the layout. Only the Login into the Scrollview is working at the moment. I don't use auto layout, i did the constrains as described. And the Scrollview itself is working but everything inside is not touchable. How is the best way to share it?

Comment: It should be touchable if you add your buttons in a subview using `scrollView.addSubview(yourViewIncludingButton)`.

Comment: Are your buttons declared in your ViewController and do they have `@IBAction` or targets?

Comment: @NetflixAndChill - your labels, buttons and fields are subviews of a `UIView`, that is a subview of the scroll view. Set the background color of that `UIView` to red and run your app. See if you see the red view.

Answer (score 0):

Set following property of `UIScrollView` to enable touch event of `UIButton`

```
scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
scrollView.isExclusiveTouch = true
scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = true
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = true
```

Comment: Sorry I am new in Xcode I came from Android Studio. I think you found my problem this sounds good. But where can I change propertys that are not in the object inspector / attributes inspector (right)? User interaction enabled is there but the other attributes I don't find.

Comment: Hi @netflixAndChil those are the property is only you can assign programmatically, IBOutlet UIscrollview and then assign those properties.